# Searching between two dropdown menu in window form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I achieved search through one dropdown menu.

```
 private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM magzines where issue_number = '"+comboBox1.Text+"'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
            }
        }
```

please help me how i can search through two dropdown menu?

Comment: your query not clear, give at clear

Answer (score 0):

You should change to [paramertised query](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and not concatenate the SQL string as you're doing.  To answer the question, add a second dropdown and use [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187922.aspx) in the query...

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM magzines where issue_number BETWEEN '"+comboBox1.Text+"' AND '"+comboBox2.Text+"'";
```

Example using params...

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
      string query = "SELECT * FROM magzines where issue_number BETWEEN '@comboOne' AND '@comboTwo'";
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("comboOne", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("comboTwo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
          da.Fill(table);            
      }
    }
```

Comment: thkyou cristiandev
i want to add advance search functionality almost 7 to 8 dropdownmenu. please help me

Comment: how to apply a condition?if one dropdown is not selected and other are selected?

Comment: You initially asked for *two*, not the questions is changing?

Comment: Soory i mistakenly write 2. my question is for multiple dropdown

Comment: You wrote *two* in both the heading and body of the question?! I think you should address the issue of using two, and maybe open a new question for multiple - since the answer to multiple won't actually answer the above question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BindingSource

```
 BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = view1;

// Set the data source for the DataGridView.
datagridview1.DataSource = dt ;

//The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'";
```

for more visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28VS.90%29.aspx